# Call function on button click/link

Tags: prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I have a **button on .tpl** page and **working function** in Product class (for example: `{Product::getProductAttributesIds()}`)

I like to call this function only after "click" or "submit" of button

If I make `"action={Product::getProductAttributesIds()}"` - **function will be called immediatelly**  while page load

How to run this function only after button click?*

PS 1.7; need to use only controller and .tpl file

Answer (score 0):

The method will run only during loading(in .tpl). If you want to call it separate you need to create an ajax request(in a controller) which will call the method or you can hide the result of the method on a page during its loading and later show/use it on click. And then use javascript onClick method in your button to call ajax or show hidden result